# EditText ellipsize (three dot)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, longtext, ellipsize

I want to customize android edit text so that when clicked outside, it will automatically scroll back to first and show three dots at the end if the text is too long.
I have customized it to try it to run well but not yet optimized, please refer to it and if possible, give me a more optimal way.

```
class CustomTextInputEditText(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
    TextInputEditText(context, attrs) {
    private var dotsString: String? = null
    private var storeString: String? = null
    private var mWidthMeasureSpec: Int = 0
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        Log.e("CustomTextInputEditText", "onMeasure 1: $mWidthMeasureSpec")
        mWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
    }
    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        Log.e("CustomTextInputEditText", "onMeasure 2: $mWidthMeasureSpec")
        mWidthMeasureSpec = width
        setText(text, BufferType.NORMAL)
    }
    override fun setText(text: CharSequence?, type: BufferType) {
        if (!isFocused) {
            if (!text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val tmpString = text.toString()
                val textWidth = this.paint.measureText(tmpString)
                Log.e("CustomTextInputEditText", " textWidth = " + textWidth)
                Log.e("CustomTextInputEditText", " mWidthMeasureSpec = " + mWidthMeasureSpec)
                storeString = tmpString
                dotsString = tmpString
                if (mWidthMeasureSpec > 0 && mWidthMeasureSpec <= textWidth + context.convertDpToPx(69f)) {
                    if (dotsString?.length!! >= (mWidthMeasureSpec / textWidth * tmpString.length - 5).toInt() && (mWidthMeasureSpec / textWidth * tmpString.length) >= 5)
                        dotsString = tmpString.substring(0, (mWidthMeasureSpec / textWidth * tmpString.length - 5).toInt()) + "..."
                }
                Log.e("CustomTextInputEditText", "setText: $dotsString")
            }
            Log.e("CustomTextInputEditText", "not focus: $dotsString")
            super.setText(dotsString, type)
        } else {
            Log.e("CustomTextInputEditText", "focus: $dotsString")
            super.setText(storeString, type)
        }
    }

    override fun onFocusChanged(focused: Boolean, direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect)
        if (focused) {
            setText(storeString)
        } else {
            val tmpString = text.toString()
            val textWidth = this.paint.measureText(tmpString)
            storeString = tmpString
            if (mWidthMeasureSpec <= textWidth) {
                dotsString = tmpString.substring(
                    0,
                    (mWidthMeasureSpec / textWidth * tmpString.length - 10).toInt()
                ) + "...";
                setText(dotsString)
            }
        }
    }
    fun getRawText(): String {
       if (storeString == null)
           return ""
        else
           return storeString!!
    }
}
```

My xml

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_select_address"
                style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:hint="@string/select_address"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_10">

                <vn.leaftech.f99fruits.utils.custom_view.CustomTextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_select_address"
                    style="@style/TextInputEditTextLayoutStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_24"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/margin_16"/>


            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I tried the code bellow but it doesn't work:

```
 android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:editable="false"
```